# Extract signals with certain frequenceis from a data sample using python

Tags: frequency-spectrum, discrete-wavelet-transform

I did not major in signal processing, and I do not know a lot about some possibly very basic facts, so although SE has some questions related to this, I still have some confusion.

I am given a data sample, data collected with an equal time difference (daily.) I am also informed that there are three major periodical components of the signal, with known periods (say 30 days, 80days, and 200days.) How can I extract those three components in Python, using wavelet and FFT?

I have already in my hand a MODWT method that I can just use directly, so I do not need to worry about that.

To extract each component, what I tried is:

DWT the sample data, create a filter using the following:

```
center_frequency1 = 1/period
fr=np.fft.fftfreq(wave_modwt.size//4,1)
gauss_win = np.exp(-(fr - center_frequency1) ** 2 /(center_frequency1+0.001) ** 2)+np.exp(-(fr + center_frequency1) ** 2 / (center_frequency1+0.001) ** 2)
```

Multiply this filter with wave_modwt, and then IDWT the product back.

I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the filter step, because I was just checking previous questions on SE and changing random things to make the code run (as you can see the FFT function appeared very randomly, and for some reason, the program is still running, so I kept it there.)

Any advice on either the outline of the work or the details is appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with just using the fast Fourier transformation (FFT?)  It provides frequency, amplitude, and phase.  You can get the same information from just the wavelet transform as well.

Comment: Hello @flypig, and welcome to DSP.SE. Why do you want to use a method based on Wavelets and the FFT to extract the individual components - wouldn't (band pass) filters be more effective? Do you know anything about the spectra of the individual components? The separation gets much more difficult if their spectra overlap, potentially caused by some kind of harmonic oscillations. What is your code doing - is your goal to perform filtering in the frequency-domain by multiplying the signal spectrum with a filter function? I recommend plotting the data first and then deciding how to continue.

Comment: @JRE I would do this with FFT as well, but my boss is asking me if I can modify it to wavelet. Now neither of us is professional in signal processing, so I am not sure if there is any special reasoning behind his request. If the fact is that FFT is better than wavelet in terms of extracting certain waves, then I will confirm with him his intentions.

Comment: The wavelet transformation will give you frequency, amplitude, and phase as well.

Comment: @applesoup thank you for your welcome! For the individual components, I know their period, but not much about the amplitudes. In fact, I believe it is expected that the extreme values of each period can be different. My ultimate goal is to find the three components and then generate a wave without noise (anything other than the three components). And yes, I am trying to perform the filtering in the frequency domain by multiplying the filter with my signal after transformation. Also, do you mind elaborating on bandpass filters you mentioned?